# Stop propagation of SendingMail event in .NET PasswordRecovery control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, event-handling

I have a [`PasswordRecovery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control whose behavior I need to modify.  When the `SendingMail` event is fired, the event handler is called.  In the event handler, I have defined behavior to write a `MailMessage` to a queue (for processing later).  So far, so good.  The problem is the event continues on and tries to use the built-in method `LoginUtil.SendPasswordMail`.  This requires smtp server information, which I don't want to provide (since it would violate the design of our application).

Here's the event handler:

```
protected void vendorWebPasswordRecovery_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = this.vendorWebPasswordRecovery.UserName;

    try
    {
        MailMessage emailMessage = e.Message;

        var messageData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        messageData.Add("toEmail", emailMessage.To[0].ToString());
        messageData.Add("subject", emailMessage.Subject + " from the queue!");
        messageData.Add("body", emailMessage.Body);

        //Write the message out to the queue
        SendPasswordResetEmail(messageData, userName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoggingHandler.Write("MailMessageEventArgs did not contain expected data: - " + ex.Message, LogCategoryType.Verbose, TraceEventType.Verbose, 1, ex);
    }                

    //Compilation error: "MailMessageEventArgs doesn't contain a definition for 'Handled'"
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

How can I stop the event from continuing on and calling the built-in method?  I tried setting the `MailMessageEventArgs` to handled, but that's a compilation error.  Is this even the right approach?

Comment: Did you try e.Cancel instead of e.Handled? Sample here: http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/11/10/163371.aspx

Comment: I did and it worked perfectly.  If you want to put that in an answer I'll mark it as such :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use e.Cancel to cancel the event and stop sending default email.

Sample here: scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/11/10/163371.aspx